# JS - VB.Net - CBC Encryption

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I want to encrypt a specific string in js and in vb.net. I want the same encrypted string to come out in both.

For that I use the AES CBC Encryption.
Now I found the following code for JS:

```
const ENC_KEY = "bf3c199c2470cb477d907b1e0917c17b"; // set random encryption key
const IV = "5183666c72eec9e4"; // set random initialisation vector
```

and in VB.Net:

```
 Dim KEY_128 As Byte() = {41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41}
 Dim IV_128 As Byte() = {41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41}
```

The issue with that is that I only have the code for VB.Net with the Key as Byte and in Js as String.
Now I don't know how to get the same Key as Byte as the String. Does someone have an Idea with that?

In case you need further code for the encryption:

JS:

```
var encrypt = ((val) => {
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', ENC_KEY, IV);
let encrypted = cipher.update(val, 'utf8', 'base64');
encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
return encrypted;
});

message.channel.send(encrypt(phrase));
```

VB.Net:

```
Private Sub btnEncrypt_Click()
    Dim sPlainText As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText) Then
        Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, Me.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        cryptoStream.Write(Me.enc.GetBytes(sPlainText), 0, sPlainText.Length)
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())
        memoryStream.Close()
        cryptoStream.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `TypedArray` instead of string when calling `crypto.createCipheriv`:

```
const arrayKey = new Int8Array(32);
arrayKey[0] = 41;
arrayKey[1] = 41;
...
arrayKey[31] = 41;
```

and then:

```
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', arrayKey, IV);
```

Do the same for IV.

[More information about TypedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)